Subobjects in rigid abelian tensor categories
$\require{AMScd}$
In Tannakian Categories (prop. 1.17) we are given the following:

Let $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ be a rigid abelian tensor category. If $U$ is a subobject of $\mathbf{1}$, then $\mathbf{1} = U \oplus U^{\bot}$, where $U^{\bot} = \ker(\mathbf{1} \to U^{\vee})$. Consequently, $\mathbf{1}$ is a simple object if $\mathrm{End}(1)$ is a field.

The proof starts with tensoring the SES $0 \to U \to \mathbf{1} \to V \to 0$ (where $V = \mathrm{coker}(U \to \mathbf{1})$) with $- \otimes U$, which is exact by prop. 1.16, giving us (up to natural isomorphism) the SES $0 \to U \otimes U \to U \to V \otimes U$.
We are then giving the following diagram, which Deligne/Milne claims is commutative and exact:
$$\begin{CD} U @>>> \mathbf{1} @>>> V\\ @AAA @AAA @AAA\\
U \otimes U @>>>U @>>> V \otimes U
\end{CD}.$$
I understand why it is exact and why the leftmost diagram commutes. But why does the rightmost diagram commute? I don't understand the rest of the proof (so I'd be happy with a more thorough explanation), but right now I am mainly trying to understand why the diagram is commutative.
See here for a tangential question (although it does not adress the same point, AFAICT): A question about subobjects of the unit in a rigid abelian tensor category.

Commutativity of both squares follows from the fact that for $A \to B$ and $C \to D$ two morphisms, the square $$\begin{CD} A \otimes D @>>>B \otimes D\\ @AAA @AAA \\
A \otimes C @>>>B \otimes C
\end{CD}$$ commutes. This commutativity follows from the definition of bifunctor, i.e. because the analogous square commutes in the product category.
Substituting $A = D = \mathbf{1}$, $B =V$, $C=U$ gives the righthand square.

Oh, yes, ofc! =). Thanks for the quick answer.
